# jmeter csv data POST json collection

Tags: json, csv, collections, jmeter

JSON body for an HTTP request needs to look like:

```
{
  "OrderId":"234",
  "SupplierId":"JJ889",
  "OrderedProducts": [
    {
      "ProductId":"123",
      "Sku":"ABC123",
      "Description":"Thing 1"
    },
    {
      "ProductId":"435",
      "Sku":"XYZ987",
      "Description":"Thing 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
ProductId,Sku,Description
123,ABC123,Thing 1
435,XYZ987,Thing 2
....
```

But when I substitute `"ProductId":"${ProductId}"` (and the other variables for sku and description) in the HTTP Request body data I end up with:

```
{
  "OrderId":"234",
  "SupplierId":"JJ889",
  "OrderedProducts": [
    {
      "ProductId":"123",
      "Sku":"ABC123",
      "Description":"Thing 1"
    },
    {
      "ProductId":"123",
      "Sku":"ABC123",
      "Description":"Thing 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I ensure my collection of products is unique (i.e. different CSV line) per request?

Comment: Are there always 2 products per request?

Comment: No, not always 2 products.  I'd love to be able to have a variable number of products per request.  I suppose I could structure the CSV to have 4 or 5 products per line and have multiple requests each with up to 5 products and just sort of fudge it that way.  Still would like a more elegant solution

Comment: In which case, as far as I can tell, you'll have to use a beanshell preprocessor to custom construct your JSON before using it in a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have always 2 products per request, just organize your CSV this way:

> ProductId1,Sku1,Description1,ProductId2,Sku2,Description2

And use the new variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) and [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) functions like:

```
{
  "OrderId":"234",
  "SupplierId":"JJ889",
  "OrderedProducts": [
    {
      "ProductId":"${__javaScript("${__StringFromFile(file.csv,,,)}".split("\,")[0],)}",
      "Sku":"${__javaScript("${__StringFromFile(file.csv,,,)}".split("\,")[1],)}",
      "Description":"${__javaScript("${__StringFromFile(file.csv,,,)}".split("\,")[2],)}"
    },
    {
      "ProductId":"${__javaScript("${__StringFromFile(file.csv,,,)}".split("\,")[0],)}",
      "Sku":"${__javaScript("${__StringFromFile(file.csv,,,)}".split("\,")[1],)}",
      "Description":"${__javaScript("${__StringFromFile(file.csv,,,)}".split("\,")[2],)}"
    }
  ]
}
```

- `__StringFromFile()` function reads next line from `file.csv` each time it's being called
- `__javaScript()` function allows executing arbitrary JavaScript code, in above case [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to break the line into ProductId, Sku and Description.

See [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) User Manual chapter and [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on JMeter functions.